# How to approach Graph Theory Proofs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Show that if $G$ is a simple graph with $n$ vertices (where
$n$ is a positive integer) and each vertex has degree greater than or
equal to $n−1$, then the diameter of $G$ is $2$ or less.

I ended up getting very stuck on this question. Proving by contradiction is usually how I go about getting a better understanding of what is actually being asked for but when I tried this one I ended up doing something with the neighbors of the vertices and I just got off on the wrong track.  How would you have approached this question and in general what are things to look out for with proofs like this?

Comment: Diameter 2 means that any two vertices are either connected directly, or have a path between them via one other vertex. Suppose there are two vertices that are not directly connected, then...

Comment: Can you draw such a graph for small $n$ like $3, 4, 5$? This might tell you what you expect $G$ to look like in general.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something the question seems trivial. As there are only $n$ vertices and the graph is simple, the degree of each vertex must be exactly $n-1$ and hence there is an edge joining each distinct pair of  vertices so the diameter is 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** (Assume $n \ge 2$.) If every pair of two points is connected by an edge, the diameter is $1$.

Now, suppose two points $v$ and $w$ are not connected by an edge. Let $V_v$ and $V_w$ denote the set of vertices connected to $v$ and $w$, respectively. If $V_v \cap V_w \neq \varnothing$, then you are done. (Why?)
Note that $|V_v|, |V_w| \ge n - 1$. (Why?)
On the other hand, $|V_v \cup V_w| \le n$. Thus, we have $$|V_v \cap V_w| = |V_v| + |V_w| - |V_v \cup V_w| \ge 2(n-1) -n = n - 1 \ge 1.$$
Can you conclude now?